# C# Calculator I made is giving nonsense results

Tags: c#, math, calculator

When I give the calculator input: 1+11= The answer it gives is 14. If I phrase the line "total=num1+num2;" I get the right result, but when I phrase the line: "total+=num1+num2;" it gives me 14 and I don't know why this is so. This means I can't use the total in the way I intended as I have to overwrite it and can't have a running total. :-/

```
`using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Calculator
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public double num1;
        public double num2;
        public double total;
        public string activestring;
        public int operand;
        public bool Isnum1;
        public bool Isnum2;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //a #1 button on a calculator.
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text += 1;
            activestring += 1;

            if (Isnum1)
            {
                num2 = double.Parse(activestring);
                if (operand == 1)
                {
                    total += num1 + num2;
                }
            }
        }
        // a + button on a calculator.
        private void buttonPlus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Isnum1)
            {
                operand = 1;
                num1 = double.Parse(activestring);
                activestring = "";
                Isnum1 = true;
                textBox1.Text += "+";
            }
        }

        // an = button on a calculator.
        private void buttonEQ_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Clear();
            textBox1.Text = total.ToString();
        }
    }
}`
```

Comment: this is a good time to debug your own program

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugging-absolute-beginners?view=vs-2019

Comment: I was expecting `total += num1 + num2` to be in the handler for `buttonEQ`.  That was surprising to me that you put it in the handler for `button1`.

Comment: I wanted it to calculate on the fly but only output the answer when you hit =. If you look at the calculator on your phone you'll see its calculating the result while you're still typing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @bolov that debugging your program would be a good learning exercise here, but if you're struggling, and for the academic purpose of learning how to improve what you've got rather than someone telling you a totally different way, the following is what's going on:

What you program is doing is (focusing on just the bits that cause the bug):

**Button '1' is clicked which sets the following things:**
 - activestring = "1"
**Button '+' is clicked which sets the following things:**
 - num1 = 1
 - activestring = ""
 - isnum1 = true;
**Button '1' is clicked which sets the following things:**
 - activestring = "1"
 - num2 = 1
 - total = 2 (total(0) + num1(1) + num2(1))
**Button '1' is clicked again which sets the following things:**
 - activestring = "11"
 - num2 = 11
 - total = 14 (total(2) + num1(1) + num2(11))

This is a result of trying to accumulate numbers which have only been partially written.
There are lots of horrible ways you could fix this up inside the '1' button click code (e.g. parsing before and after updating `activestring`, and then taking off the previous value and adding the new one), but it feels like using 2 totals as in the code example below would achieve your goal in a slightly tidier way without breaking too far away from the structure you've set out:

(I've also tweaked it to support continued addition (multiple calls to '+') as it seems like that's what you were eventually aiming for).

(Disclaimer: I've not actually run this through a compiler at all, but it should help to set you on the right track).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Calculator
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public double num1;
        public double num2;
        public double total;
        public string activestring;
        public int operand;
        public bool Isnum1;  
        public bool IsPrevCharNumeric;  // New

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //a #1 button on a calculator.
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text += 1;
            activestring += 1;

            if (Isnum1)
            {
                num2 = double.Parse(activestring);
                if (operand == 1)
                {
                    total = num1 + num2;  // Changed
                }
                isPrevCharNumeric = true;  // New
            }
        }
        // a + button on a calculator.
        private void buttonPlus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsPrevCharNumeric)  // Changed
            {
                operand = 1;
                total = num1 + double.Parse(activestring);  // Changed
                num1 = total;                               // Changed
                activestring = "";
                Isnum1 = true;
                IsPrevCharNumeric = false;                  // New
                textBox1.Text += "+";
            }
        }

        // an = button on a calculator.
        private void buttonEQ_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Clear();
            textBox1.Text = total.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```